# php regex find string patterns

Tags: php, regex

Hello I'm not good with regex and I would really appreciate if someone could help me out.
I need a regex function that will find all patterns that start with : and are followed by at least 1 letter and maybe numbers until next occurrence of a symbol.

For example  `:hi/:Username@asdfasfasdf:asfs,asdfasfasfs:asdf424/asdfas`

As you can see here there are 4 occurences. 
What I would like to achieve is to end up with an array containing:

```
['hi','Username','asfs','asdf424']
```

PS. Letters might be in other languages than english.

Downvoting for no reason... congrats

This is what I'm using so far but I suppose it would be easier with regex

```
public function decodeRequest() {

    $req_parts = $this->getRequestParams(); // <-array of strings


    $params = array();

    for ($i=0; $i < count($req_parts); $i++) {

        $starts = mb_substr($req_parts[$i], 0, 1, 'utf-8');
        $remains = mb_substr($req_parts[$i], 0, mb_strlen($req_parts[$i]), 'utf-8');

        if ($req_parts[$i] == ':') {
            array_push($params,$remains);
        }


    }

    return $params;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want support for non-ASCII characters it is better to use `\p{L}` with `u` switch:

```
$s = ':hi45/:Username@asdfasfasdf:asfsŚAAÓ,asdfasfasfs:asdf424/asdfas';
if (preg_match_all('/:([\p{L}\d]+)/u', $s, $arr))
   var_dump($arr[1]);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "hi45"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "Username"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "asfsŚAAÓ"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "asdf424"
}
```

Comment: Damn dude you have helped me in other regex question regarding htaccess clean url rewritting. :) saved my ass twice thank you again!

Comment: Thanks for remembering me and glad that it all worked out for you.

Comment: Mate may I ask something extra in case I need it. How could we modify this regexp to work untill next occurance of / or - instead of any symbol?

Comment: To match string `untill next occurance of / or -` you can use `[^/-]+`

Comment: so the complete regex would look like '/:([\p{L}\d][^/-]+)/u' ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38187/discussion-between-panagiotis-george-raditsas-and-anubhava)

Comment: Actually use this one: `'~:([^/-:]+)~u'`

Answer (score 1):

```
/:([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)/
```

- you need at least a letter [a-zA-Z]
- then any sequence of valid characters (letters, numbers) [a-zA-Z0-9]*

[See demo](http://regex101.com/r/lH6sU1)

```
<?php
    $string = ":hi/:Username@asdfasfasdf:asfs,asdfasfasfs:asdf424/asdfas";
    preg_match_all('/:([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)/', $string, $matches);
    print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hi
    [1] => Username
    [2] => asfs
    [3] => asdf424
)
```

Comment: how should I modify this in order to have at least 1 letter after the : sign ?